# parse whole section of property file into a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have a property file that is used by a python script that looks like so:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()

config['section'] = {'a': 'value1',
                   'b': 'value2',
                   'c': 'value3',
                   'd': 'value4',
                   'e': 'value1'}

with open('/path/to/propFile_autolaunch.ini', 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

In my python script I then want to parse all the variables from the section `section`. Now I am doing it manually with the following code snippet:

```
# imports
from configparser import ConfigParser
propFile = '/path/to/propFile_autolaunch.ini'
propParser = ConfigParser()
propParser.read(propFile)

# parse the variables manually
var_a = propParser.get('section', 'a')
var_b = propParser.get('section', 'b') # then I repeat this for all options
```

Eventually I need to parse all options from the section `section`, so I was wondering if there is a way to parse the whole section `section` into a dictionary (e.g. `d_params`), so that I can parse all variables in that dict with a single command such as:

```
for key, val in d_params.items():
    exec(key + '=val')
```

Obviously I could declare the variables in a dictionary in my python script itself, so that I could circumvent the use of the property file at all. But the thing is I have multiple sections in my property file, so I would like to keep it for any configuration, instead of hard-coding the variables for a single section in my python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to convert a section in an .ini file to a dictionary in a single operation, rather than constructing the dictionary one setting at a time.  If so, then I believe the following code snippet will solve your problem.  Specifically, an ini file section can be used directly as a `dict` initializer as shown here:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
propFile = '/path/to/propFile_autolaunch.ini'
propParser = ConfigParser()
propParser.read(propFile)

# this is the import part...
d_params = dict(propParser["section"])

print(d_params)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'value1', 'b': 'value2', 'c': 'value3', 'd': 'value4', 'e': 'value1'}
```